# Unable to export image to drive in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working with Imerg data and after calculating the total rainfall from monthly averages there is an error while after I run the `export.image.toDrive`. The error is:

> Attempted 1 time
> Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)

Also, the projection is giving me this error:

> Line 36: projection is not defined

Here is the code I am using

```js
    //Total Rainfall
    var imerg = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06").select('precipitation');
    
     var year = 2019;
      var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
      var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year');
      var filtered = imerg
      .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
      
    var total = function(img){
      var year = 2019;
      var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
      var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year');
      var hoursInyear = endDate.difference(startDate, 'hours');
      return img.addBands(img.multiply(hoursInyear).rename('precip_mm_month'));
    };
    
    filtered = filtered.map(total);
    
    var palette = [ 
      '000096','0064ff', '00b4ff', '33db80', '9beb4a',
      'ffeb00', 'ffb300', 'ff6400', 'eb1e00', 'af0000'
    ];
    
    var precipitationVis = {min: 0.0, max: 10000, palette: palette};
    
    Map.addLayer(filtered, {bands:'precip_mm_month', palette:palette, min:0, max: 5000})
    print(filtered);
    
var projection = total.select('precip_mm_month').projection().getInfo();
    
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: filtered,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      description: 'Precipitation_2019',
      crs: projection.crs,
      crsTransform: projection.transform
      region: roi,
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, an `ImageCollection` was found where an `Image` is needed. Specifically, `Export.image.toDrive()` can only be used to export single images, not image collections.

If you want to export the same (mosaiced) view that you get from `Map.addLayer()`, then use

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: filtered.mosaic(),
  ...
```

I can't help you with your additional problem because the code you have presented has different errors than you mentioned (`total` is not an image but a function, so `total.select()` fails).